# __construct() method call but handle() function not call in laravel job

Tags: laravel-5.4, supervisord, redis-server, laravel-jobs

I am trying to execute job through `dispatch()` method using

1. laravel 5.4
2. redis-server
3. supervisor

I have done `queue` config like `'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'redis')`.

1. I am call dispatch() method in my `app/Services` file

> dispatch(new SavePropertyImages($pid_list));

2. the following is my job file in `app/Jobs`:

   ```
   namespace App\Jobs;

   use App\Property;
   use App\Services\CreaBase;
   use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
   use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
   use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
   use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
   use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

   class SavePropertyImages implements ShouldQueue
   {
       use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

       protected $pid;
       protected $creaBase;
       public $timeout = 300;
       public $tries = 1;
       /**
        * Create a new job instance.
        *
        * @return void
       */
       public function __construct($pid)
       {
           $this->pid = $pid;
       }

       /**
        * Execute the job.
        *
        * @return void
       */
       public function handle()
       {
               $this->creaBase = new CreaBase();
           if (!$this->creaBase->isLogin){
                   $this->creaBase->init();
           }
               $this->creaBase->saveAllImages("Property", $this->pid);
       }
   }
   ```

When I call a `dispatch(new SavePropertyImages($pid_list))` method, the job's `__construct()` method calls, but it does not call `handle()` function.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

bingo, I got the answer

my `handle()` function does not call. because I set a `supervisor` but not start the `supervisor` process that's why my `queue:work redis` process not start and my job does not assign to `redis` server and my job was not to execute.

first off all I start my `supervisor` service and my `queue` works fine.